# ffmpeg reverse video resolution after compression

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I'm trying to compress a video to `mp4` format with `ffmpeg`.

With scale filter:

```
cmd = "-i, "+in+" -vf scale=480:-2,setsar=1:1, "+out;
```

Or as simple as this:

```
cmd = "-i, "+in+" "+out;
```

If I try this command, the outPut will be fine in many players like potPlayer(win) or mxPlayer(android), But in some players like kmPlayer.v3(win) it's stretched. with or without scale filter.

I tried the same video compression with `Handbrake` so I find out there is nothing wrong with my player.

The result is the same with all videos that I compressed with [ffmpeg library](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java)

And there is another problem which is more annoying, the outPut video resolution gets reversed. for Example:

> Input :  w1280 h720
>
> Output : w720 h1280

I googled a lot but I found nothing.

Comment: If you take your video in portrait mode on the Android device, it may have [rotation metadata](https://addpipe.com/blog/mp4-rotation-metadata-in-mobile-video-files/) set, and your ffmpeg failed to use it correctly with scale filter.

Comment: Try to add **-noautorotate** to ffmpeg command line.

Comment: @AlexCohn Yes, `-noautorotate` solved the case. Of course if you want to answer the question I will accept it. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you record video in portrait mode on, it may have [rotation metadata](https://addpipe.com/blog/mp4-rotation-metadata-in-mobile-video-files/) set, and ffmpeg cannot use it correctly with scale filter.

You can add **-noautorotate** option to ffmpeg command line, or maybe there is a way to correct the metadata.

Comment: in android i am adding -noautorotate in ffmpeg command, but ffmpeg is not recognising . please take a look at this Command:                       String[] cmd = {"-i",videoPathtem,"-i",watermarkImagePath,"-filter_complex","overlay=0:0","-strict","-2","-metadata:s:v:0","rotate="+videoRotation,resultVideoPath};

Comment: @MuhammadHassaan you have `rotate` command, so **ffmpeg** will ignore `-noautorotate`.

Comment: it still not working, because ffmpeg is not recognizing this command, is this command and all other commands are written in particular order in ffmpeg?